# @async in spring behaviour is synchronous

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

i have written a piece of code for checking the `@Async` annotation behavior in Spring framework.

```
@RequestMapping( value="/async" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView AsyncCall(HttpServletRequest request)
  {
        async1();
        async2();
    return new ModelAndView("firstpage");
  }

  @Async
  private void async1(){
      System.out.println("Thread 1 enter");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("Thread 1 exit");
  }

  @Async
  private void async2(){
      System.out.println("Thread 2 enter");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("Thread 2 exit");
  }
```

output of this code is as follows.

```
Thread 1 enter
Thread 1 exit
Thread 2 enter 
Thread 2 exit
```

By looking at this output it seems like that these two `@Async` function call are synchronous itself.

As of i know these two are different threads and should run asynchronously itself.

After changing the code according to spring proxy call logs which are printing are like.

Main Thread name: http-apr-8080-exec-8

```
Thread 1 enter
Async-1 Thread Name: neutrinoThreadPoolExecutor-1
Thread 1 exit
Thread 2 enter
Async-2 Thread Name: neutrinoThreadPoolExecutor-1
Thread 2 exit
```

name of the thread for both async calls are same and still it seems that asynchronous behavior is not presented.

Comment: Proxy advice isn't applied to self-calls...

Comment: i have changed the code with spring proxy advice.

Answer (score 13):

These are the situation where `@Async` was not working for me

1. `@EnableAsync` was missing
2. `@Async` method was not public
3. `@Async` annotated method was called from another method of same class. Probably bypassing the async proxy code and just calling plain method.

Answer (score 4):

Spring's `@Async` annotation has two rules that you need to follow.

1. It must be applied to `public` methods only
2. Self-invocation – Calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. 
And self-invocation doesn’t work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

Comment: Method can be package-private

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Async in Spring Application? In Spring Boot, you can do something like.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

The @EnableAsync annotation switches on Spring’s ability to run @Async methods in a background thread pool.

Comment: is there any option to enable it through web.xml. ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the methods from outside your current class. Otherwise the *spring magic* wont get executed.

So try something like this:

```
@Inject
MyAsyncService asyncService;

@RequestMapping( value="/async" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView AsyncCall(HttpServletRequest request) {
    asyncService.async1();
    return new ModelAndView("firstpage");
}
```

**MyAsyncService**

```
@Component
public MyAsyncService {
    @Async
    public void async1() {
         //code
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration for enabling async.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncWorkerConfig {

    @Bean(name = "abcExecutors")
    public ExecutorService ch3Executors() {
        int corePoolSize = 6;
        int maxPoolSize = 6;
        int keepAliveTime = 100000;

        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                        .setDaemon(false)
                        .setNameFormat("abc-parser-t-%d").build());
    }

}
```

Create class and add async to the method.

```
 @Service
public class AsyncFileProcessor {

    @Async("abcExecutors")
    public void process(final String filePath){
      //your code logic
  }

}
```